# ReactJS - Different Component vs Conditional Rendering

Tags: reactjs, performance

Let's say I'm building out a `<TextInput />` component.

I have 3 variations. In variation #1, the label is above the textinput; in #2 the label is the placeholder and moves up when clicked; in #3 it's inside the input above the placeholder.

**Question1:** Performance wise, which method of having the 3 variations is faster in terms of load times in the UI - putting it all in one component with conditional rendering in the JSX everywhere and having a prop to toggle between the three variations, or having 3 totally separate components and then importing a TextInput object and calling a specific variation in this fashion `<TextInput.VariationA />`?

**Question2:** Does importing the full TextInput object somehow lag the component instead of just importing `VariationA` by itself? Say for example if there are 1000 components inside the main import (like when importing Icons).

```js
// This TextInput has TextInput.VariationA 
// TextInput.VariationB and TextInput.VariationC
import TextInput from "myCustomTextInput"
// vs
import { VariationA } from "myCustomTextInput"
```

Comment: Aside performance thing(I don't think you will ever notice difference) it's much more flexible to have 3 different components(maybe with extracting common logic into re-used "input layout" that will never be directly imported elsewhere and/or some custom hooks for handling interactions). There are low-to-zero chance you will ever want to switch "type" from A to B in the middle. And if it's single component - yes, with conditional rendering - it still harder to maintain, things that looked as "common part" initially will become more and more different. Having all in single place restricts you.

Comment: @skyboyer Thanks for your answer. I used to do it all in one single component and this is what I'm finding exactly... it's very cumbersome to read and maintain and I was thinking of doing it the 3 component way as you suggested. I also never thought about considering props that aren't conditional to be a different component (specifically like in this case), all great thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think performance is going to problem, but I suppose you would handle it three different class with one component. You can give classnames via props where form component is used. And three different css styling will probably works.

I haven't try it before but I think it might works.